# reactjs: how to update a variable outside of reader.onload() function from within the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
  handleFile(files) {
    
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var dataSet;
    
    reader.onload = function(file) {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      var kb = byteArray.length / 1024;
      var mb = kb / 1024;
      console.log('kb', kb, 'mb', mb)
      
      dataSet = dicomParser.parseDicom(byteArray);
      console.log('within function: ', dataSet)
      
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    console.log('outside reader.onload function: ', dataSet)
}
```

When the above code runs, the `kb` and `mb` get printed and `console.log('within function: ', dataSet)` is printed. I can confirm that dataSet has value in it.

However, `console.log('outside reader.onload function: ', dataSet)` says that `dataSet` is `undefined`.

How can I update the `dataSet` variable from within the `onload` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of async await to make it feel like synchronous code + the new promise based blob reading methods `blob.arrayBuffer()`

```js
async function handleFile (files) {
    var file = files[0]
    var KiB = file.size / 1024
    var MiB = KiB / 1024
    console.log('KiB', KiB, 'MiB', MiB)

    var arrayBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer()
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
    var dataSet = dicomParser.parseDicom(byteArray)
    
    console.log(dataSet)
}
```

Also if you are dividing with 1024, then use the correct unit KiB and MiB
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units

Comment: This works like a charm. I've learnt something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait until the onload is called before you can output it.

What is happening at the moment is this:

```
   var dataSet = undefined;
   // reader onload hasn't been called yet.
   console.log('outside reader.onload function: ', dataSet)
```

reader.onload kicks in after the console.log

as such, try this:

```
 handleFile(files) {
    
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var dataSet;

    function performOutput() {
     console.log('outside reader.onload function: ', dataSet)
    }
    reader.onload = function(file) {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      var kb = byteArray.length / 1024;
      var mb = kb / 1024;
      console.log('kb', kb, 'mb', mb)
      
      dataSet = dicomParser.parseDicom(byteArray);
      performOutputHere();
      
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    
}
```

Or if its cleaner for you.

```
reader.onloadend = function() {
      console.log('what does dataset look like now? ', dataSet)
};
```